# Python encoding UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have been plugging away at this for hours and I just can't seem to get to the bottom of it.
I have been through this website in detail and although others seem to have a similar problem but their solutions given just don't work for me.

I have a python script which reads the HTML of a website and uses beautiful soup to find things like the head, body, H1's etc... and then store them in a utf-8 MySQL table.

Seems straight forward but I keep running into:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte xxxxxx
```

When I encode. I have tried everything I can find to stop this happening but to no avail.
Here is one version of the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(strIndexPage)
strIndexPageBody = str(soup.body)
strIndexPageBody = strIndexPageBody.encode('ascii', 'ignore') # I know ignore is not best practice but I am really not interested in anything outside the ascii character set
strIndexPageBody = strIndexPageBody .replace('"','&quot;')
strIndexPageBody = strIndexPageBody .replace("'","&rsquo")
```

An earlier version where I tried to convert to utf-8 works better, but I end up with the

```
`
```

character present in some of the HTML which breaks the MySQL insert/update.
Obviously I have tried searching for this character and replacing it, but then python tells be I have a non ascii character in my code!

I have read tons are articles that say I should be looking at the encoding for the HTML first, decode and then encode to suit, but the encoding does not always come back from BS, and/or not declared within the HTML.

I am sure there is a simple way around this but I can't find it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't `&rsquo` end in a semicolon? Also it's not the same as `'`.

Comment: Please stop focusing on the last two lines - they are not where the error is. It errors on the encoding as the error message suggests.

Comment: When Python complains about a non-ascii character in your code, it probably means you need to add a `# coding: utf-8` magic comment at the top (it needs to be one of the first two lines). That's assuming you're saving the Python file in UTF-8.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236437/python-unicodeencodeerror-how-can-i-simply-remove-troubling-unicode-characters

Comment: Interesting - will give it a shot tomorrow - thanks for your input.

Comment: Upvote for Mark Byers who also helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that you're getting a *decode* error from a call to encode. This is the ugliest part of Python 2: it lets you try to encode a string that is already encoded, by first decoding it as ascii. What you're doing is equivalent to this:

```
s.decode('ascii', 'strict').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

I think this should do what you expect:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(strIndexPage)
strIndexPageBody = unicode(soup.body)
strIndexPageBody = strIndexPageBody.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Note that we're calling unicode, so we get a unicode string that we can validly try to encode.

Comment: If `soup.body` is a `str` object which encodes non-ascii characters, then passing it to `unicode` will give a `UnicodeDecodeError`; on the other hand, if it's already a unicode object, then passing it to `unicode` is redundant.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Its a `BeautifulSoup.Tag` object, which can be flattened with either `str` or `unicode`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I probably should have guessed that :/

Comment: @Thomas K: Thank you very much for your help - Your explanation is succinct and I now understand where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup's [`UnicodeDammit`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit) should be able to detect the encoding of a document even when it isn't specified.

What happens when you run this on the page in question?:

```
from BeautifulSoup import UnicodeDammit

UnicodeDammit(html_string).unicode
```

What specific line of code is throwing the error and can we have a sample of problematic HTML?

Comment: I Skimmed over that earlier - I will give it a try and report back - thanks for your help.

Comment: The thing is, UnicodeDammit is by default when parsing a page with BeautifulSoup, you shouldn't have to do anything special.

Comment: I see - BS does not error - the error occurs when I try to encode it.

Comment: If you're encoding unicode to ascii, and you're setting it to ignore characters that can't be encoded, it shouldn't be raising `UnicodeDecodeError` exceptions. What is the line of code that raises the exception and what is the object being encoded?