# Unable to extract data from BeautifulSoup object after utf-8 conversion due to 'str' typecasting

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build my own web scraper using Python. One of the steps involves parsing an HTML page, for which I am using *BeautifulSoup*, which is the parser recommended in most tutorials. Here is my code which **should** extract the page and print it:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlToRead = "http://www.randomjoke.com/topic/haha.php"
handle = urllib.urlopen(urlToRead)
htmlGunk =  handle.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlGunk, "html.parser")
soup = soup.prettify()
print (soup)
```

However, there seems to be an error when I do `soup.prettify()` and then print it. The error is:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in
>   position 16052: ordinal not in range(128)

To resolve this, I googled further and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5236869/4258892) answer of SO which resolved it. I basically had to set the encoding to `'utf=8'` which I did. So here is the modded code (last 2 lines only):

```
soup = soup.prettify().encode('utf-8')
print (soup)
```

This works just fine. The problem arises when I try to use the `soup.get_text()` method as mentioned on a tutorial [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Whenever I do `soup.get_text()`, I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_text'

I think this is expected since I'm encoding the soup to 'utf-8' and it's changing it to a `str`. I tried printing `type(soup)` before and after `utf-8` conversion and as expected, before conversion it was an Object of the `bs4.BeautifulSoup` class and after, it was `str`.

How do I work around this? I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong and there's a proper way around this. Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with Python, so please bear with me

Comment: If your only problem is non-working `print` you can do `encode` on the print lines.

Comment: so basically `print(soup.get_text().encode('utf-8')`)?

Comment: Yes, why not? You don't need to replace your `soup` object just to print it.

Comment: I get the error `'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

Comment: just print it or use some other variable to save it other than soup

Comment: Yup, that's because `soup.prettify()` returns `unicode` and you've lost your original `bs4.BeautifulSoup` object. This error was already in your code.

Comment: Yes you are right. It works now. Can you tell me *When* (in what scenario) we should use `soup.prettify()`? It seems that when you want to extract text, we should not be using it. It seems to me that `soup.prettify()` only gives us a navigable string, is that correct?

Comment: "Navigable string"? It just prints the parsed tree as one document, it is not useful for anything else.

Comment: There are hundreds of similar reports, doesn't one of them address your issues? Maybe it would help you if you extracted a minimal example first, as the guidelines require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not discard your original `soup` object. You can call `soup.prettify().encode('utf-8')` when you need to print it (or save it into a different variable).

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlToRead = "http://www.randomjoke.com/topic/haha.php"
handle = urllib.urlopen(urlToRead)
htmlGunk =  handle.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlGunk, "html.parser")
html_code = soup.prettify().encode('utf-8')
text = soup.get_text().encode('utf-8')

print html_code
print "#################"
print text



# a = soup.find()
# l = []
# for i in a.next_elements:
#     l.append(i)
```